# cant get values of item in foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I can't get the values in the view that I sent from the controller.

I tried two ways but I can't make them appear in a div. I must show the values in a table or label.

Controller:

```
List<string> tsList = new List<string>();
ts.tarih = ogrenci.Tarih;
tsList.Add(ts.tarih);
tsList.Add(ogrenci.TaksitSayisi);
tsList.Add((36000 / Convert.ToInt32(ogrenci.TaksitSayisi)).ToString());

string odeme=(36000 / Convert.ToInt32(ogrenci.TaksitSayisi)).ToString();
List<TaksitSaysi> lstTaksit = new List<TaksitSaysi>();
lstTaksit.Add(new TaksitSaysi()
{
    taksitSayisi = ogrenci.TaksitSayisi,
    tarih = ogrenci.Tarih, tutar = odeme
});
return View("Index",lstTaksit);
```

I first try tsList but can't show the item in a label or div.

Now i try lstTaksit. I tried several way in my view again but none of them work.

I want then item to be text of a label. I relaized that when I wrote the code in an if, for, or foreach etc. it doesnt show it.  For example i created a div and write some text in it and it doesnt show on page

My view is:

```
@model IEnumerable<TaksitSaysi> 
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {

            **<div>deneme</div>**
            <table id="Table" >
            @for (int i=0;i<Convert.ToInt32( item.taksitSayisi) ;i++ )
            {
                <text> <tr><td> @item.tutar </td></tr></text>
            }
            </table>
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model you will want to create your custom data type.

Here is a simple example that may help you get the idea:

Model:

```
public class MyType
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
    public string Item3 { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var myList = new List<MyType>();

        var customType1 = new MyType();
        customType1.Item1 = "Item 1a";
        customType1.Item2 = "Item 2a";
        customType1.Item3 = "Item 3a";
        myList.Add(customType1);

        var customType2 = new MyType();
        customType2.Item1 = "Item 1b";
        customType2.Item2 = "Item 2b";
        customType2.Item3 = "Item 3b";
        myList.Add(customType2);

        return View(myList);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.MyType>
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.Item1;
            @item.Item2;
            @item.Item3;
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```